# Como reemplazar un Charfield por iconos en Django

Tags: python, html5, django, django-models, django-forms

sepan disculpar si no expreso correctamente la pregunta.
Tengo la intención de que una persona pueda elegir entre varios sistemas operativos y que al elegir se imprima en un Card de Bootstrap un icono, osea reemplazar caracteres por iconos las cuales utilizo de la página iconmoon, no he intentado nada por que realmente no tengo absolutamente idea de como desarrollar eso, ante cualquier duda responderé lo mejor posible, gracias de ante mano, les dejaré una foto de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es iconmoon, viene con una carpeta font y lleva esto adentro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y también viene con un style.css

Esto es mi template:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es mi models.py
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al momento de elegir un sistema operativo (me imagino que es atraves de *choices*), en una vista de detalle **por ejemplo** ¿quieres mostrar un icono en ves del texto o choice elegido?. Por otra parte, los iconos los tienes descargados? es decir en la carpeta `static/`? o son enlaces a los iconos? (Si pudieras agregar mas detalles para la proxima seria de mucha ayuda... :] )

Comment: Si, es un choice y quiero mostrar un icono en lugar del texto, es de iconmoon con la carpeta fonts y styles.css que viene predeterminado

Comment: No conozco como funciona *iconmoon*. Pero los iconos, son clases CSS o archivos (.svg, .png, etc)?

Comment: Son SVG y se inserta con un span como ejemplo: <span class="icon-windows8"></span> añadiré una captura de como es el iconmoon

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0):

Tu modelo debería ser así:

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    platform = [
        ('windows', 'Windows'),
        ...
    ]

    platformTags = {
        'windows': 'windows8',
        ...
    }

    choice_platform = MultiSelectField(choices=platform)

    def get_platform_tags(self):
        return [
            (platform, self.platformTags.get(platform)) for platform in self.choice_platform
        ]
```

**Cabe recalcar que los choices `platform` y `platformTags`, deben estar definidas dentro de la clase o modelo `Platform`, si no es asi, no funcionara, ademas de que es de buena practica.**

El método `get_platform_tags`, retornara una lista con tuplas, el primer elemento de cada tupla es el valor real que se establece en el modelo respecto a los choices y el segundo elemento de cada tupla son las clases CSS correspondientes.

Entonces, tu template debería ser así:

```
{% for platform, tags in product.get_platform_tags %}
    <span class="{{ tags }}"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

**Si no es necesario saber en el template** a que plataforma pertenecen las clases CSS, entonces no es necesario retornar una lista con tuplas, si no simplemente las clases CSS, después de todo, tu objetivo es mostrar los iconos.

Entonce el método `get_platform_tags` podría ser así:

```
def get_platform_tags(self):
    return [self.platformTags.get(platform) for platform in self.choice_platform]
```

Simplemente retorna una lista de las clases CSS en base a los sistemas operativos seleccionados. Entonces, podrías mostrar los iconos en tu template tal que así:

```
{% for tags in product.get_platform_tags %}
    <span class="{{ tags }}"></span>
{% endfor %}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: En la parte de def get_<field_name>_tags(self): no lo entiendo, que debe ir dentro del <field_name>?

Comment: El nombre del campo, el campo `CharField` que mencionaste. Aunque, el metodo puede llamarse como tu quieras, pero con ese nombre es mas legible.

Comment: Y si está el OS_SYSTEM_CHOICES por qué se hace un get al OS_SYSTEM_CHOICES_TAGS ? 
Lo puse tal cual y no me ha funcionado, obviamente con mis valores en el models.py

Comment: `OS_SYSTEM_CHOICES_TAGS` es un diccionario, que tiene las clases CSS para cada sistema operativo (`OS_SYSTEM_CHOICES`), ademas el `get` es un método de diccionario, esto es ya es de Python, no de Django. Por otra parte, actualiza tus pregunta con tu modelos, para ver que estas haciendo mal y el porque no te funciona.

Comment: Actualicé para que lo veas mejor, por que sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Normal... usas un campo que funciona totalmente diferente a un `CharField` con `choices`... para la próxima, adjunta tus modelos y estos detalles tan cruciales... ya investigare como funciona ese campo y así actualizar mi respuesta...

Comment: Acabo de actualizar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Comment: He probado e intentado que funcione, por que si has colocado la respuesta es por que te ha funcionado, entonces estaba pensando, mi formulario que es un Card de Bootstrap tiene un for que hace un get a un archivo product y donde está todo, quizá el for que añado hace que no muestre el icono, puede ser eso? y si lo es, se puede llamar al archivo platform en el mismo for? osea junto al product, como: product and platform

Comment: De hecho acabo de probar esto: <span class="icon-{{product.platforms}}"></span> pero solo pudo aparecer uno, por ejemplo android, cuando cambio a otro no aparece, solo parece Android

Comment: Cree un proyecto Django, mas que nada para ver como funcionaba ese campo  `MultiSelectField` y me funciona perfectamente. Algo estas haciendo mal, y no se si son los templates o los modelos... porque no mejor pones los bucles `for` de mi respuesta a secas, a lo mejor hay un `display: none` por ahí....

Comment: Te juro que he intentado muchas cosas de lo que me enseñaste y no me funciona, no sé si haber mencionado esto sería mejor, el model de Platform lo llamo a un model Product donde está un foreignkey de esta manera:     platforms = models.ForeignKey(Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
Perdón por no llegar a comprender del todo... no quiero ser una molestia

Comment: Entonces el el formulario lo tengo así {% for product in products %}

Comment: Pues si accedes a las plataformas atraves de una relacion, las cosas cambian un poco, pero por sentido comun deberias poder mostrar los iconos... seria algo así: `{{ product.platforms.get_platform_tags }}`, es Python, nada del otro mundo.... por otra parte toma en cuenta que es una relacion uno a muchos.